# SideMenu and tabs screen issue

Tags: codenameone

I've a couple of tabs in a form. If I open side menu and try to slide the side menu out, rather than closing the side menu the components of the tabs move. How can I solve it?

Have a look at the video [here.](https://youtu.be/418Kg7IEUt4)

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a bug we should find a way to fix. However, I'm not sure if we can do so easily as both the tabs and side menu rely on the pointer event listeners of the parent `Form`.

I'm afraid that at this time the only workaround is to disable tab swiping.